# Alternative of amazon-linux-extras in Amazon Linux 2023

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-extras

We have amazon-linux-extras for Amazon Linux 2 but, what is the alternative of amazon-linux-extras in Amazon Linux 2023 and how to install it

Comment: This is one of the questions in the [faq](https://aws.amazon.com/linux/amazon-linux-2023/faqs/).

Comment: Cool, I saw what I was looking for in the faq

Answer (score 1):

AL2023 default package manager is DNF

Example:

`sudo dnf install postgresql15`

Answer (score 0):

There is no such package and you cannot install epel either. However you can download packages from epel and install them directly it would work in most cases, but you'll have to resolve all dependencies manually.

Comment: This response is created by Bing, right?

Answer (score -1):

I am able to install the java with this command:

```bash
sudo dnf install java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64
```